# Alternatives to a recursive CTE inside an 'exists' correlated subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, recursion, common-table-expression, correlated-subquery

I have a situation where I need to be able to see if a given person is within a user/manager hierarchy.

I need to be able to do this for a set of users against a set of rules (don't worry about this, but just to give it a bit of context)

Ideally I'd like to use a recursive CTE inside a correlated exists subquery on the where clause.

But this poses a lot of problems..

1. I don't think you can use a CTE in a subquery at all.
2. I'm on SQL 2005 with compatibility mode 80 - so I can't use cross apply... so no column parameters into UDF's for me :-(

I think what I'm trying to do is:

```
WITH UserHierarchy(UserId, ManagerId)
    AS
    (
        --Anchor Definition
        SELECT [UserId], [ManagerId] FROM [Users] WHERE [ManagerId] = [Rules].[RuleAddedByUserId] -- this needs to bind to an outer query....
        UNION ALL
        --Recursive Member definiation
        SELECT [Users].[UserId], [Users].[ManagerId] FROM [Users] 
        INNER JOIN [UserHierarchy] ON [Users].[ManagerId] = [UserHierarchy].[UserId]
        WHERE [Users].[UserId] <> [Users].[ManagerId] --don't recurse if the anchor definition matches itself (to avoid an infinate loop).
    )
```

Is there anyway of making the anchor definition dynamic in compatibility mode 80? Or an alternative approach?

Comment: And how is the anchor part alone not enough for you in the EXISTS predicate? I can't see the point of recursing further from the anchor if the recursive part is not correlated with the outer query, but only the anchor part is. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @AndriyM thanks for taking a look.The problem is that the "WITH" statement can't be inside a subquery at all, so I can't bind to an outer query (my code above is just pseudo code - sorry I should of mentioned that). Good news is, I think I'm onto a solution, I'll post it once I'm done.

Comment: Yes, I think I got that right the first time. You want something like a recursive query inside `EXISTS`, but `WITH`, which is used for building recursive queries, cannot be used in subqueries, and so you are asking this question. Is that right? Suppose you were allowed to have `WITH` in subqueries and therefore were able to build a correlated recursive subquery. Why would you need to have a recursion if it is only the anchor part that is correlated with the outer query? If the anchor returned rows, that would be enough for the EXISTS predicate to return `true`, and similarly for `false`.

Comment: So, bottom line is, you likely do not need recursion and consequently *you do not need to use `WITH`*. That, in turn, means, you can have your correlated subquery in the form of a mere `SELECT [UserId], [ManagerId] FROM [Users] WHERE [ManagerId] = [Rules].[RuleAddedByUserId]`. (Or `SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [ManagerId] = [Rules].[RuleAddedByUserId]`, as the actual column list doesn't matter for the EXISTS predicate.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AndriyM, I see now what you mean. My example was trying to replicate an issue I'm having with a larger query. Looking at it now, I don't think my example is very good. What I'm trying to achieve is figuring out if a user is below a manager in a given hierarchy.... I'll try to update my question with a more accurate example. I must admit I'm finding it tricky to explain what I'm after, as the problem is pretty epic. Thanks again for the help, I'll try to update it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there eventually! Thanks guys for the help.

Here is a snippet of the SQL I'm working on.

I just had to change my thinking, instead of seeing if a user exists under a manager within the where clause. I needed to consider the CTE a pre-filter and construct all the details I needed before hand, then do my normal filtering after i.e. the exists statements (n.b. I've not included those for brevity).

```
RulesUserHierarchy(UserId, ManagerId, PushRuleId, OnlyForSubOrdinates) -- Gets only subordinates for rules created by managers. And all users for those created by admin.
AS
(
    --Anchor Definition
    SELECT
         [Users].[UserId]
        ,[Users].[ManagerId]
        ,[RulesAnchor].[PushRuleId]
        ,[RulesAnchor].[OnlyForSubOrdinates]
    FROM [Users]
        CROSS JOIN [Rules] [RulesAnchor] --assume every user is doing every rule at this point (because the recursive statement has to be the first statement), we'll filter later.
    WHERE (([OnlyForSubOrdinates]) = 0 OR ([OnlyForSubOrdinates] = 1 AND [UserId] = [RulesAnchor].[AddedByUserId]))
    UNION ALL

    --Recursive Member definiation
    SELECT
         [Users].[UserId]
        ,[Users].[ManagerId]
        ,[RulesUserHierarchy].[PushRuleId]
        ,[RulesUserHierarchy].[OnlyForSubOrdinates]
    FROM [Users]
        INNER JOIN [RulesUserHierarchy]
            ON [Users].[ManagerId] = [RulesUserHierarchy].[UserId] --recursive hook 
            AND [RulesUserHierarchy].[OnlyForSubOrdinates] = 1 -- no point recursing if it's for everyone, as the anchor will pull back everything for us.
    WHERE [Users].[UserId] <> [Users].[ManagerId] --don't recurse if the anchor definition matches itself (to avoid an infinate loop).
)       
-- simple statement to test recursion above, will be filtering the inclusions here (e.g. the other mega exists statements)
SELECT [UserId], [ManagerId], [PushRuleId], [OnlyForSubOrdinates] FROM [RulesUserHierarchy]
```

---

**EDIT**

I realised I didn't need the cross join in the recursive definition. Although it won't effect the outcome of the latter exists statements, it isn't good for performance.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to create a recursive CTE that has, for each user, one row for each ancestor of that user in the tree.  Then you can use the CTE to filter for ancestors.  For example, with this tree:

```
Bob
|-Alice
  |-Jim
```

The CTE would return something like:

```
User  Ancestor Level
----  -------- -----
Bob   NULL     1
Alice Bob      1
Jim   Alice    1
Jim   Bob      2
```

The `Level` column ends up not being very important, but I found it helped when I was writing the query.

Here's a sample script which identifies all users who are under Alice in the hierarchy:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    UserId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(25),
    ManagerId int
);
GO

INSERT INTO Users (UserId, Name, ManagerId)
SELECT 1, 'Bob', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Steve', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Chris', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Alice', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Roger', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Tony', 5;
GO

WITH all_ancestors AS (
    SELECT
        u.UserId,
        u.Name,
        u.ManagerId AS AncestorId,
        1 AS level
    FROM
        Users AS u
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        alla.UserId,
        alla.Name,
        u.ManagerId AS AncestorId,
        alla.level + 1
    FROM
            all_ancestors AS alla
        INNER JOIN
            Users AS u
        ON
            alla.AncestorId = u.UserId
)
SELECT
    u.*
FROM
        Users AS u
    INNER JOIN
        all_ancestors AS a
    ON
        u.UserId = a.UserId
WHERE
    a.AncestorId = 4; -- Alice
GO

DROP TABLE Users;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Cheran, interestingly thats kinda the approach I've taken. +1 from me, I'll post my solution in a few mins.

Comment: I was looking for something similar, but my thoughts eventually took a different turn and I wasn't satisfied with what I found then. Your solution is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

How many levels of hierarchy can there be in the `Users` table? I'd expect it to be reasonably low. I wonder if it is low enough to try multiple nested `EXISTS` tests, like this:

```
… /* your main query here */
WHERE …
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Users] u1
    WHERE [UserID] = @UserID
      AND (
        [ManagerId] = [Rules].[RuleAddedByUserId]
        OR EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM [Users] u2
          WHERE [UserID] = u1.[ManagerID]
            AND (
              [ManagerId] = [Rules].[RuleAddedByUserId]
              OR EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM [Users] u3
                WHERE [UserID] = u2.[ManagerID]
                  AND (
                    [ManagerId] = [Rules].[RuleAddedByUserId]
                    OR EXISTS ( … /* and so on, until you've covered
                                     all possible levels */
                    )
                  )
              )
            )
        )
      )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I can't guarantee the level of nesting and I've got to make it work in any nesting scenario, but thanks for the post.